# Gravity in stone

Tags: electromagnetism, gravity

I want to ask is it possible for a stone to have some magnetic power different from power that we see in ordinary metal magnets (something like earth gravity that attract everything). Someone told me that he saw a stone that attract other smaller stone but did not attract metals.

Is it practically possible in science?

Comment: Hi Farzad. Welcome to Physics.SE. Your question(s) is (are) quite ambiguous. First, what do you mean by "power" - because power (in physics) is *roughly* *energy per second*. Can you rephrase it? (or) Is that what you've asked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perhaps explainable through simple magnetism.  In as much as the stone to stone attraction is easily seen with two pieces of magnetite, while trying to attract a non magnetic piece of metal would show no effect.

The forces we know of are gravity, electromagnetism, weak nuclear force and strong nuclear force.